# How to get the class of a field by javascript?

Tags: javascript

i want to execute an if condition based on its class

```
var follow = document.getElementById('follow');

if(the class of the variable follow is active){

do this...


}
else{

do this...


}
```

how can i do it in javascript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about

```
if(follow.className == "active")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `className` property of your element.

```
if(follow.className == 'active') {
    // do something
}
else {
    // do something else
}
```

Note, however, that an element such as `<div class="active right">` wouldn't work with that code, because className would return 'active right'. To put that another way, it will work with elements that have **only** the 'active' class, but not all elements that have the 'active' class.

You could, instead, use a regular expression match like so, to detect elements that have the active class (and potentially others):

```
if(follow.className.match(/.*active.*/)) {
    // do something
}
else {
    // do something else
}
```

Comment: You should use `.test()` rather than `.match()` if you only care about a yes-it-matches/no-it-doesn't result. Also, won't your regex match on `<p class="inactive">`? "." matches any character...

Answer (score 2):

Bearing in mind that more than one class may be specified for the same element:

```
<p class="active bright wavy">
```

You can do this:

```
if (/(^| )active( |$)/.test(follow.className)) {
   // do something
}
```

The property to check the class from JavaScript is `.className` because `class` is a reserved word. (Reserved for future use: it doesn't do anything at the moment.)

Or if you're going to be doing it a lot, you could define a function:

```
function elementHasClass(el, cl) {
   return (new RegExp("(^| )" + cl + "( |$)")).test(el.className);
}

if (elementHasClass(follow, "active")) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `follow.className`, since `class` is obviously reserved.

Answer (score 0):

Use this if you this type of check more often:

```
Element.prototype.hasClass = function(classToCheck){

            if(this.className == classToCheck)
               return true;
            else if(this.className.indexOf(classToCheck + ' ') ==0) 
               return true
            else if(this.className.indexOf(' ' + classToCheck) == (classToCheck.length - 1) ) 
               return true
            else if (this.className.indexOf(' ' + classToCheck + ' ') >= 0)
               return true;

           return false
        }
```

Call it with

```
if(document.getElementById('myId').hasClass('classIWantToCheck')){
//do the stuff
}else{
// do other stuff :(
}
```

Comment: That else if test means that the function will erroneously return true if the element has multiple classes and one of them has a name that contains the desired class name. E.g., `class="inactive test"` and `someElement.hasClass("active")`

Comment: yes nnnnnn that is true, your regex is better. I will edit mine to work with indexOf too.